# jquery gives syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

for this jquery in my jsp which uses some strut tags which gets convert to html as shown below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        var tbl = $("#table");      
        $("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
            $('<tr><td><arch:datePicker property="expirationDate" tabindex="${requestScope.tabIndex}" styleId="expirationDate" value="test" imageSrc="/image/content/calendar_icon.gif" alt="date picker"   onchange="validateDateFormat( this );" /></td></tr>').appendTo(tbl); }); });
</script>
```

which parse the following html codes:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        var tbl = $("#table");      
        $("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
            $('<tr><td><input id="expirationDate" name="expirationDate" onchange="validateDateFormat( this );" class="sspdatepicker" type="text" alt="date picker State the date in numeric format of MonthMonthDayDayYearYearYearYear. Do not state dashes or slashes. For Example, January 1st 2013 should be stated as 01012013." value="test" maxlength="10"/><a aria-describedby="date" href="#" class="accCalendar datePicker" id="dateIconexpirationDate"><img src="/COMETSHDPortalApp/image/content/calendar_icon.gif" id="expirationDate" alt="date picker" class="sspdatepicker" title="expirationDate Calendar" tabindex="0"/></a><script type="text/javascript"> $A.bind(window, 'load', function(){ $A.setCalendar("UniqueCalendarIdexpirationDate", $A.getEl("dateIconexpirationDate"),$A.getEl("expirationDate"), false, function(ev, dc, targ){targ.value = dc.range[dc.range.current.month].nameShort + '/'    + dc.range.current.mDay + '/' + dc.range.current.year;dc.close(); targ.focus();},{className: 'calendar'});});</script></td></tr>').appendTo(tbl); }); });
</script>
```

Advance thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Strut generated HTML block is fine.

You have single quote, double quote issue on the second one looks like. You need to skip the single quote inside another single quote: Try the parser with following version:

```
  $(function (){
      var tbl = $("#table");      
      $("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
          $('<tr><td><input id="expirationDate" name="expirationDate" onchange="validateDateFormat( this );" class="sspdatepicker" type="text" alt="date picker State the date in numeric format of MonthMonthDayDayYearYearYearYear. Do not state dashes or slashes. For Example, January 1st 2013 should be stated as 01012013." value="test" maxlength="10"/><a aria-describedby="date" href="#" class="accCalendar datePicker" id="dateIconexpirationDate"><img src="/COMETSHDPortalApp/image/content/calendar_icon.gif" id="expirationDate" alt="date picker" class="sspdatepicker" title="expirationDate Calendar" tabindex="0"/></a><script type="text/javascript"> $A.bind(window, \'load\', function(){ $A.setCalendar("UniqueCalendarIdexpirationDate", $A.getEl("dateIconexpirationDate"),$A.getEl("expirationDate"), false, function(ev, dc, targ){targ.value = dc.range[dc.range.current.month].nameShort + \'/\'    + dc.range.current.mDay + \'/\' + dc.range.current.year;dc.close(); targ.focus();},{className: \'calendar\'});});</script></td></tr>').appendTo(tbl); }); });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, error is gone but the date calendor does not work when i click.

Comment: please disregard my previous comments. It didn't work and now i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" after trying your version